# when i run crawler on EC2, why didn't it work well?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, scrapy

i setted docker on ec2 and upload crawler scrapy code. since yesterday when i run ec2, it could collect data well. but suddenly now it doesn't work well. i guessed it is EC2 problem, because it could work well till today lunch time.

then i try to check EC2 condition, typed `df -h`, it showed

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           796M   19M  778M   3% /run
/dev/xvda1      7.7G  7.7G     0 100% /
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/11107
/dev/loop1       33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/11402
/dev/loop2       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1988
/dev/loop3      132M  132M     0 100% /snap/docker/796
/dev/loop4       34M   34M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/3552
tmpfs           796M     0  796M   0% /run/user/1000
```

surely yesterday `/dev/xvda1` this part('used') wasn't 100%.
so i tried to increase size of `/dev/xvda1` volume on EBS.
i hope this trying can solve the issue.

after EBS, when i type `lsblk` on EC2 terminal it showed this

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0     7:0    0  32.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/11107
loop1     7:1    0  33.3M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/3552
loop2     7:2    0  32.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/11402
loop3     7:3    0  55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/1988
loop4     7:4    0 131.6M  1 loop /snap/docker/796
xvda    202:0    0    16G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0     8G  0 part /
```

anyway i wonder how to delete `/dev/xvda1`size. because i have plan that my crawler will work periodically openly, but always if i have to increase volume size, it will make me messy.
please help me,
how can my crawler can work without `/dev/xvda1` worry.

when i typed`sudo find / -type f -size +10M -exec ls -lh {} \;`
it showed this

```
sudo: unable to resolve host ip-172-31-79-98: Resource temporarily unavailable
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 19M Mar  8 10:47 /snap/snapd/11402/usr/bin/snap
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13M Mar  8 10:47 /snap/snapd/11402/usr/lib/snapd/snap-bootstrap
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12M Mar  8 10:47 /snap/snapd/11402/usr/lib/snapd/snap-preseed
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 22M Mar  8 10:47 /snap/snapd/11402/usr/lib/snapd/snapd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 19M Feb 10 10:44 /snap/snapd/11107/usr/bin/snap
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13M Feb 10 10:44 /snap/snapd/11107/usr/lib/snapd/snap-bootstrap
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12M Feb 10 10:44 /snap/snapd/11107/usr/lib/snapd/snap-preseed
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 22M Feb 10 10:44 /snap/snapd/11107/usr/lib/snapd/snapd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 51M Feb  5 15:56 /snap/docker/796/bin/containerd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 26M Feb  5 15:56 /snap/docker/796/bin/ctr
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 29M Feb  5 16:02 /snap/docker/796/bin/dnet
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 82M Feb  5 15:58 /snap/docker/796/bin/docker
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 31M Feb  5 16:02 /snap/docker/796/bin/docker-machine
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 98M Feb  5 16:00 /snap/docker/796/bin/dockerd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13M Feb  5 16:03 /snap/docker/796/bin/runc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 26M Mar 16  2020 /snap/docker/796/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudat                                                                                                                                                                                                                      a.so.60.2
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 24M Dec 21 16:37 /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/3552/amazon-ssm-agent
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 39M Dec 21 16:37 /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/3552/ssm-agent-worker
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 27M Dec 21 16:37 /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/3552/ssm-cli
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 36M Dec 21 16:37 /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/3552/ssm-document-worker
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13M Dec 21 16:37 /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/3552/ssm-session-logger
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 34M Dec 21 16:37 /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/3552/ssm-session-worker
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 21M Mar 22 07:02 /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-1039-aws
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 21M Mar 22 07:01 /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-1038-aws
-rw------- 1 root root 16M Mar 23 07:14 /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/resource1
-rw------- 1 root root 16M Mar 23 07:14 /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/resource1_wc
-rw------- 1 root root 32M Mar 23 07:14 /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/resource0_wc
-rw------- 1 root root 32M Mar 23 07:14 /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/resource0
-r-------- 1 root root 128T Mar 23 07:14 /proc/kcore
find: ‘/proc/2374/task/2374/fdinfo/6’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/proc/2374/fdinfo/5’: No such file or directory
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 15M Mar  8 14:14 /usr/bin/runc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 16M Mar  2 20:16 /usr/bin/rootlesskit
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 19M Feb  2 08:21 /usr/bin/snap
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 111M Mar  2 20:16 /usr/bin/dockerd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 30M Mar  8 14:14 /usr/bin/ctr
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 55M Mar  8 14:14 /usr/bin/containerd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 11M Nov 23  2018 /usr/bin/lxc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 69M Mar  2 20:16 /usr/bin/docker
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 20M Feb 27 15:10 /usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpytho                                                                                                                                                                                                                      n2.7.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 20M Feb 27 15:10 /usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpytho                                                                                                                                                                                                                      n2.7-pic.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 26M Mar 16  2020 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.60.2
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18M Nov 23  2018 /usr/lib/lxd/lxd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13M Feb  2 08:21 /usr/lib/snapd/snap-bootstrap
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 22M Feb  2 08:21 /usr/lib/snapd/snapd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 36M Jan 26 15:33 /usr/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu/lib                                                                                                                                                                                                                      python3.6m-pic.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 37M Jan 26 15:33 /usr/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu/lib                                                                                                                                                                                                                      python3.6m.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 25M Dec  4  2019 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/cc1plus
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 22M Dec  4  2019 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 23M Dec  4  2019 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/cc1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 62M Mar  2 20:16 /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 36M Mar  2 20:16 /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-app
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 21M Mar 22 07:05 /home/ubuntu/crawlab-1/.git/objects/pack/pack-6c0a8218eeb814173c677e3df54850423986d710.pack
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 26M Apr 26  2018 /var/lib/apt/lists/us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic_universe_i18n_Translati                                                                                                                                                                          on-en
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11M Mar 22 15:48 /var/lib/apt/lists/us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic-updates_main_binary-amd                                                                                                                                                                          64_Packages
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 49M Apr 26  2018 /var/lib/apt/lists/us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic_universe_binary-amd64_P                                                                                                                                                                          ackages
-rw------- 2 root root 132M Mar 22 07:14 /var/lib/snapd/cache/aa3d5fe426c66baa3261f1641b9b5fe284cd08a16761eb765438cb5396b1c0ba96abe1e29                                                                                                                                                                          6135543871dbe68423be6b1
-rw------- 2 root root 56M Feb 24 17:36 /var/lib/snapd/seed/snaps/core18_1988.snap
-rw------- 2 root root 34M Feb 24 17:36 /var/lib/snapd/seed/snaps/amazon-ssm-agent_3552.snap
-rw------- 1 root root 32M Feb 24 17:36 /var/lib/snapd/seed/snaps/snapd_11036.snap
-rw------- 1 root root 33M Mar 23 04:18 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd_11402.snap
-rw------- 2 root root 56M Feb 24 17:36 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core18_1988.snap
-rw------- 2 root root 34M Feb 24 17:36 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/amazon-ssm-agent_3552.snap
-rw------- 2 root root 132M Mar 22 07:14 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/docker_796.snap
-rw------- 1 root root 33M Mar 22 09:39 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd_11107.snap
-rw-r----- 1 root root 14M Mar 23 06:45 /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/containers/5f951fb4ee5e008ad09cf3e5a86bbd5c25061a0a11237                                                                                                                                                                          8c1b6123a12d2c16c27/5f951fb4ee5e008ad09cf3e5a86bbd5c25061a0a112378c1b6123a12d2c16c27-json.log
-rw------- 1 999 docker 14M Mar 23 06:41 /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/volumes/b5276a9f65fc8a8995ce9a76c50bcd27ddd90043201d4a6                                                                                                                                                                          f609dda8aae79d462/_data/collection-10-5521340255836326071.wt
-rw------- 1 999 docker 100M Mar 23 06:45 /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/volumes/b5276a9f65fc8a8995ce9a76c50bcd27ddd90043201d4a                                                                                                                                                                          6f609dda8aae79d462/_data/journal/WiredTigerLog.0000000034
-rw------- 1 999 docker 100M Mar 23 06:35 /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/volumes/b5276a9f65fc8a8995ce9a76c50bcd27ddd90043201d4a                                                                                                                                                                          6f609dda8aae79d462/_data/journal/WiredTigerPreplog.0000000001
-rw------- 1 999 docker 100M Mar 23 06:35 /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/volumes/b5276a9f65fc8a8995ce9a76c50bcd27ddd90043201d4a                                                                                                                                                                          6f609dda8aae79d462/_data/journal/WiredTigerPreplog.0000000002
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12M Mar 13 04:01 /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/b1991d45bb2288ac16dcab9c1860d3eb821543b2e66a22f                                                                                                                                                                          e261d9a159dd2019e/diff/usr/local/bin/redis-server
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 27M Mar 17  2020 /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/7a9d391c4792c7234e369212d9e4300b3279bb7a805a187                                                                                                                                                                          36a83f30428033492/diff/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.66.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 26M Aug  8  2020 /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/7a9d391c4792c7234e369212d9e4300b3279bb7a805a187                                                                                                                                                                          36a83f30428033492/diff/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/cc1plus
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 24M Aug  8  2020 /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/7a9d391c4792c7234e369212d9e4300b3279bb7a805a187                                                                                                                                                                          36a83f30428033492/diff/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/lto1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 25M Aug  8  2020 /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/7a9d391c4792c7234e369212d9e4300b3279bb7a805a187                                                                                                                                                                          36a83f30428033492/diff/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/cc1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 18M Apr 23  2020 /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/7a9d391c4792c7234e369212d9e4300b3279bb7a805a187                                                                                                                                                                          36a83f30428033492/diff/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_universe_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4
-rw------- 1 root root 15M Mar 22 08:07 /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/60c66677cf21304fe0dd7cd0143564d909529e65fef7411                                                                                                                                                                          d7a1a1c98f3e88add/diff/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.HNlE5E/Default/Cache/b5f47fbc4d23c5f6_0
-rw------- 1 root root 15M Mar 22 08:05 /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/60c66677cf21304fe0dd7cd0143564d909529e65fef7411                                                                                                                                                                          d7a1a1c98f3e88add/diff/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.diyKvW/Default/Cache/b5f47fbc4d23c5f6_0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 73M Mar 23 06:42 /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/60c66677cf21304fe0dd7cd0143564d909529e65fef7411                                                                                                                                                                          d7a1a1c98f3e88add/diff/tmp/chrome.deb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12M Jan 27 03:32 /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/60c66677cf21304fe0dd7cd0143564d909529e65fef7411                                                                                                                                                                          d7a1a1c98f3e88add/diff/usr/local/bin/chromedriver
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root staff 11M Mar 22 07:27 /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/60c66677cf21304fe0dd7cd0143564d909529e65fef741                                                                                                                                                                          1d7a1a1c98f3e88add/diff/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/chromedriver_py/chromedriver_linux64
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root staff 16M Mar 22 07:27 /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/60c66677cf21304fe0dd7cd0143564d909529e65fef741                                                                                                                                                                          1d7a1a1c98f3e88add/diff/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/chromedriver_py/chromedriver_mac64
-rw------- 1 root root 19M Mar 22 07:27 /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/60c66677cf21304fe0dd7cd0143564d909529e65fef7411                                                                                                                                                                          d7a1a1c98f3e88add/diff/root/.cache/pip/http/6/0/4/2/9/60429761adcdcb005ac1b1419b8c7b286bf36316aa97d5f62b7ccb34
-rw------- 1 root root 19M Mar 22 07:26 /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/60c66677cf21304fe0dd7cd0143564d909529e65fef7411                                                                                                                                                                          d7a1a1c98f3e88add/diff/root/.cache/pip/http/e/f/1/7/2/ef17289f5b2b98078e36fd05289a14ec9579924ee0366839cdf7611a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 165M Mar 11 23:57 /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/60c66677cf21304fe0dd7cd0143564d909529e65fef741                                                                                                                                                                          1d7a1a1c98f3e88add/diff/opt/google/chrome/chrome
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu 20M Jan 22 17:13 /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/c0c98c129cd60c3d3e895eda9c5417178012f18e515                                                                                                                                                                          9971c54372cccfc5004f9/diff/usr/bin/mongoexport
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu 20M Jan 22 17:13 /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/c0c98c129cd60c3d3e895eda9c5417178012f18e515                                                                                                                                                                          9971c54372cccfc5004f9/diff/usr/bin/mongorestore
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 51M Dec 19  2013 /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/c0c98c129cd60c3d3e895eda9c5417178012f18e5159971                                                                                                                                                                          c54372cccfc5004f9/diff/usr/bin/mongo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 62M Dec 19  2013 /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/c0c98c129cd60c3d3e895eda9c5417178012f18e5159971                                                                                                                                                                          c54372cccfc5004f9/diff/usr/bin/mongos
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu 20M Jan 22 17:13 /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/c0c98c129cd60c3d3e895eda9c5417178012f18e515                                                                                                                                                                          9971c54372cccfc5004f9/diff/usr/bin/mongoimport
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu 16M Jan 22 17:13 /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/c0c98c129cd60c3d3e895eda9c5417178012f18e515                                                                                                                                                                          9971c54372cccfc5004f9/diff/usr/bin/bsondump
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu 19M Jan 22 17:13 /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/c0c98c129cd60c3d3e895eda9c5417178012f18e515                                                                                                                                                                          9971c54372cccfc5004f9/diff/usr/bin/mongotop
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu 20M Jan 22 17:14 /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/c0c98c129cd60c3d3e895eda9c5417178012f18e515                                                                                                                                                                          9971c54372cccfc5004f9/diff/usr/bin/mongofiles
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu 19M Jan 22 17:13 /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/c0c98c129cd60c3d3e895eda9c5417178012f18e515                                                                                                                                                                          9971c54372cccfc5004f9/diff/usr/bin/mongostat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu 20M Jan 22 17:13 /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/c0c98c129cd60c3d3e895eda9c5417178012f18e515                                                                                                                                                                          9971c54372cccfc5004f9/diff/usr/bin/mongodump
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 79M Dec 19  2013 /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/c0c98c129cd60c3d3e895eda9c5417178012f18e5159971                                                                                                                                                                          c54372cccfc5004f9/diff/usr/bin/mongod
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 48M Dec 11 02:49 /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/d06370e7f6ed90afffd39f640723116f2818ff7b96619d4                                                                                                                                                                          499e497870be4df5f/diff/opt/bin/crawlab
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 48M Dec 11 02:55 /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/0d641b4b0ae1855a87a93c6f8d275be503912cf266ac69b                                                                                                                                                                          03be851e6a42b881b/diff/usr/local/bin/crawlab-server
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 73M Mar 22 07:22 /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/a033a3ea16c7b174830b9872fb6dea5a504363b42b9b9dc                                                                                                                                                                          acd8427c4a9e475a2/diff/tmp/chrome.deb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12M Jan 27 03:32 /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/a033a3ea16c7b174830b9872fb6dea5a504363b42b9b9dc                                                                                                                                                                          acd8427c4a9e475a2/diff/usr/local/bin/chromedriver
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root staff 11M Mar 22 07:19 /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/a033a3ea16c7b174830b9872fb6dea5a504363b42b9b9d                                                                                                                                                                          cacd8427c4a9e475a2/diff/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/chromedriver_py/chromedriver_linux64
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root staff 16M Mar 22 07:19 /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/a033a3ea16c7b174830b9872fb6dea5a504363b42b9b9d                                                                                                                                                                          cacd8427c4a9e475a2/diff/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/chromedriver_py/chromedriver_mac64
-rw------- 1 root root 19M Mar 22 07:18 /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/a033a3ea16c7b174830b9872fb6dea5a504363b42b9b9dc                                                                                                                                                                          acd8427c4a9e475a2/diff/root/.cache/pip/http/6/0/4/2/9/60429761adcdcb005ac1b1419b8c7b286bf36316aa97d5f62b7ccb34
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 165M Mar 11 23:57 /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/a033a3ea16c7b174830b9872fb6dea5a504363b42b9b9d                                                                                                                                                                          cacd8427c4a9e475a2/diff/opt/google/chrome/chrome
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 39M Mar 23 04:18 /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 39M Mar 23 04:18 /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 40M Mar  8 23:12 /var/cache/apt/archives/docker-ce-cli_5%3a20.10.5~3-0~ubuntu-bionic_amd64.deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 24M Mar  8 23:12 /var/cache/apt/archives/docker-ce_5%3a20.10.5~3-0~ubuntu-bionic_amd64.deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 27M Mar  9 00:39 /var/cache/apt/archives/containerd.io_1.4.4-1_amd64.deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 40M Mar  8 23:12 /var/cache/apt/archives/docker-ce-cli_5%3a20.10.4~3-0~ubuntu-bionic_amd64.deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11M Mar  1 06:20 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-aws-5.4-headers-5.4.0-1039_5.4.0-1039.41~18.04.1_all.deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 14M Mar  1 06:20 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-modules-5.4.0-1039-aws_5.4.0-1039.41~18.04.1_amd64.deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 24M Mar  8 23:12 /var/cache/apt/archives/docker-ce_5%3a20.10.4~3-0~ubuntu-bionic_amd64.deb
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 16M Mar 22 11:18 /var/log/journal/ea09dcfc1f4741e1b257d2463c341f29/system@9cf46084d404438fb64d33dbd9                                                                                                                                                                          5ecc2a-0000000000000001-0005be1a8eeb62f4.journal
```

i made new instance then i setted docker and scrapy blah blah blah...
anyway, after i crawl 1 time. when i typed `df -Th` it showed this.

```
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on           
udev           devtmpfs  3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev         
tmpfs          tmpfs     796M  1.1M  795M   1% /run         
/dev/xvda1     ext4      7.7G  5.7G  2.1G  74% /            
tmpfs          tmpfs     3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm         
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock            
tmpfs          tmpfs     3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup           
/dev/loop0     squashfs   34M   34M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/3552          
/dev/loop1     squashfs   32M   32M     0 100% /snap/snapd/11036            
/dev/loop2     squashfs   56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1988            
overlay        overlay   7.7G  5.7G  2.1G  74% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/e7965025d305ee6d51b55dee17fe547b70b51ebea9750d22e1ff55337d54b3ea/merged         
overlay        overlay   7.7G  5.7G  2.1G  74% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/414d298f3057de6461ca2d5b9ceeb290e35215500cbfdaa3d000ad7afda46359/merged         
tmpfs          tmpfs     796M     0  796M   0% /run/user/1000           
/dev/loop3     squashfs   33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/11107            
overlay        overlay   7.7G  5.7G  2.1G  74% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/b03949ee74691b6ef3f1471c37ebf58d5cd6947b8e139430b4f1c0776c06016c/merged         
overlay        overlay   7.7G  5.7G  2.1G  74% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/02159a834b6c0c51d81686f024aab575da916d001d91a7027d2c3868f7b2696e/merged
```

and after i crawl 9 times it showed this

```
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     796M  1.1M  795M   1% /run
/dev/xvda1     ext4      7.7G  7.0G  732M  91% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs     3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0     squashfs   34M   34M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/3552
/dev/loop1     squashfs   32M   32M     0 100% /snap/snapd/11036
/dev/loop2     squashfs   56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1988
overlay        overlay   7.7G  7.0G  732M  91% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/e7965025d305ee6d51b55dee17fe547b70b51ebea9750d22e1ff55337d54b3ea/merged
tmpfs          tmpfs     796M     0  796M   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop3     squashfs   33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/11107
overlay        overlay   7.7G  7.0G  732M  91% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/b03949ee74691b6ef3f1471c37ebf58d5cd6947b8e139430b4f1c0776c06016c/merged
overlay        overlay   7.7G  7.0G  732M  91% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/02159a834b6c0c51d81686f024aab575da916d001d91a7027d2c3868f7b2696e/merged
overlay        overlay   7.7G  7.0G  732M  91% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/414d298f3057de6461ca2d5b9ceeb290e35215500cbfdaa3d000ad7afda46359/merged
```

after i crawl 1 time, i wrote `du -h --max-depth=3 /var/lib | sort -h` on terminal, it showed this.

```
....
304M    /var/lib/docker/volumes/b8a9c7ac497041f99b629fdb14e9dfc283f4108d73512d3f87a79e9a5af3d0fd
306M    /var/lib/docker/volumes
350M    /var/lib/docker/overlay2/daf820fd04371808cf9213038ab552fdec5fc659d1fbf3b1643529e8ba1049e9
430M    /var/lib/docker/overlay2/3569c54068321f2973fcde4f80695f482840915df635105f6bdb68226a113741
437M    /var/lib/docker/overlay2/414d298f3057de6461ca2d5b9ceeb290e35215500cbfdaa3d000ad7afda46359
2.1G    /var/lib/docker/overlay2/b03949ee74691b6ef3f1471c37ebf58d5cd6947b8e139430b4f1c0776c06016c
2.5G    /var/lib/docker/overlay2/02159a834b6c0c51d81686f024aab575da916d001d91a7027d2c3868f7b2696e
6.3G    /var/lib/docker/overlay2
6.6G    /var/lib/docker
6.9G    /var/lib
```

after 9 times.

```
306M    /var/lib/docker/volumes/b8a9c7ac497041f99b629fdb14e9dfc283f4108d73512d3f87a79e9a5af3d0fd
308M    /var/lib/docker/volumes
350M    /var/lib/docker/overlay2/daf820fd04371808cf9213038ab552fdec5fc659d1fbf3b1643529e8ba1049e9
430M    /var/lib/docker/overlay2/3569c54068321f2973fcde4f80695f482840915df635105f6bdb68226a113741
437M    /var/lib/docker/overlay2/414d298f3057de6461ca2d5b9ceeb290e35215500cbfdaa3d000ad7afda46359
2.3G    /var/lib/docker/overlay2/b03949ee74691b6ef3f1471c37ebf58d5cd6947b8e139430b4f1c0776c06016c
2.7G    /var/lib/docker/overlay2/02159a834b6c0c51d81686f024aab575da916d001d91a7027d2c3868f7b2696e
6.7G    /var/lib/docker/overlay2
7.0G    /var/lib/docker
7.4G    /var/lib
```

Comment: You need to reduce size of data generated by your container if you want it not to fill up the filesystem. Is your container generating a lot of data or logs? Better to analyze what is taking all the disk.

Comment: @zigarn thank you to tell me that. but i can't understand, i just ran crawler but EC2's ```/dev/xvda1``` size increased. and i can't find where is ``` a lot of data or logs``` :(...

Comment: `du -h` will tell you which folders/files takes more MB

Comment: @404pio oh..  ```sudo find / -type f -size +10M -exec ls -lh {} \;``` instead of this. should i try to find other command to fine every file and folder to check data size? okok i will try !

Comment: You can also use `du -h --max-depth=1 /path | sort -h` and drill down to large directories (i.e. continue with `du -h --max-depth=1 /var/lib | sort -h` and then `du -h --max-depth=1 /var/lib/mysql | sort -h` etc

Comment: @404pio how can i prevent to increase data on EC2  after crawl ?

Comment: @TasosP.oh! i didn't know ho to drill down to large dir. thx ! i will try :)

Comment: @bayayaqd show us, how you invoke scrapy - full command

Comment: @bayayaqd do you crawl images/videos/music? or just information?

Comment: @404pio i crawl just information. after i made new instance it work well. but it still pill ```/dev/xvda1``` space.

Comment: Where do you saved crawled data? How many data you crawl? Can you show us the command you invoke to crawl?

Comment: @404pio thx to help me.my crawler work well now lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear that your EC2 instance has disk usage issue (disk gets full).
You successfully increased the volume size (as shown in `lsblk` output) but you also need to extend the file system, as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html).

Essentially, you should run `sudo growpart /dev/xvda 1` and `sudo resize2fs /dev/xvda1`. Use `df -h` again to verify.

In order to optimize performance, you should consider:

- Using a dedicated volume for your workload (i.e. mount a new, larger EBS volume on `/mnt/data` and configure your application to use this path for data storage)
- Resize this volume and/or change [type](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/volume-types/) (i.e. use provisioned IOPS SSD)

Scrapy also supports [S3 for storage](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#topics-feed-storage-s3).

You can [configure scrapy logging](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html#command-line-options) to use a specific log file (`--logfile FILE` which you can later delete) or disabled it altogether (`--nolog`, not recommended).

Comment: thank you! ```, you should run sudo growpart /dev/xvda 1 and sudo resize2fs /dev/xvda1. Use df -h again to verify.``` i tried it but it doesn't work. someone said the cause is full data on the disk... so i will just try to make new instance .....

Comment: and i wonder how can i prevent to increase data on EC2  after crawl ??

Comment: Can you elaborate on your use case? Why run a crawler if you don't need the data it crawls?

Comment: after crawls collected data go to mongodb atlas. so if after crawling it make log or data on EC2 (or docker container) it is just kind of useless data. @Tasos P.

Comment: Ok, so if you configure your app (scrappy) to reduce/disable logging or delete it after each run the issue is solved?

Comment: i alreadly made disable```log.txt```. now i couldn't do anything i made new instance to chase ```log or data``` that is made after crawling !